# Use a List of an async function in another class

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I’m basically creating a slideshow that contains texts from a list resulting from an async function.

This is the class that contains the homepage, async function and slideshow :

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.auth, this.userId, this.logoutCallback, this.profile})
      : super(key: key);

  final Auth auth;
  final VoidCallback logoutCallback;
  final String userId;
  final ProfilePage profile;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.auth, this.userId, this.logoutCallback, this.profile})
      : super(key: key);

  final Auth auth;
  final VoidCallback logoutCallback;
  final String userId;
  final ProfilePage profile;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _HomePageState();
}


class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    asyncMethod();
  }

  void asyncMethod() async {
    await getMission1();
    ....
  }
...
List<String> MissionData1 = [];
...

Future<void> getMission1() async{
    DocumentSnapshot snap = await widget.auth.MissionRetriever1();
      Map<String,dynamic> data = snap.data();
      setState(() {
      MissionData1.add(data['Q_Category']);
      MissionData1.add(data['Q_Name']);
      MissionData1.add(data['Q_Description']);
      MissionData1.add(data['Q_Score']);
      MissionData1.add(data['Q_Target']);
)};

...
Widget showTaskSlider() {
    return new Column(
      children:<Widget>[
        CarouselSlider(options: CarouselOptions(height: 30.0.h, autoPlay: true, autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3), autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800), autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn, aspectRatio: 2.0,
      onPageChanged: (index, reason){setState(() {
        _currentIndex= index;
      });},
      ),
      items: cardList.map((card){
        return Builder(builder:(BuildContext context){
          return Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.30, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: Card(color:Colors.blueAccent, child: card,),
    );
    }
    );
    }).toList()
    ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: map<Widget>(cardList, (index, url) {
            return Container(
              width: 3.0.w,
              height: 5.0.h,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: _currentIndex == index ? Colors.blueAccent : Colors.grey,
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and this is one of the classes of the slide

```
class Item1 extends StatelessWidget {
 const Item1({Key key, this.homepage}) : super(key: key); 
  final _HomePageState homepage;  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("assets/illustrations/ill_1.jpeg"), fit: BoxFit.cover,),),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,children: [Row(children:[Image(image:AssetImage("assets/images/leaf.png"),width: 8.0.w,),Text(homepage.MissionData1 == null ? "Loading" : homepage.MissionData1[1], style:TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontFamily: 'Roboto',color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF), fontSize: 15.0.sp),)]),Container(height: 20.0.h),Row(children: [Text("Dio Porco", style:TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontFamily: 'Roboto',color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF), fontSize: 25.0.sp),)])],)),    ]),
    );
  }
}
```

But when I start debugging it gives me this error

**The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Item1(dirty):
The getter 'MissionData1' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: MissionData1**

Comment: Where is `Item1` constructed?  It sounds like it's being constructed with a `null` `homepage`.  If that's unexpected, then enable null-safety or add `assert(homepage != null)` to the `Item1` constructor to see what's violating that.  If it is expected, then you need to handle that instead of accessing `homepage.MissionData1` unconditionally.

Comment: The class is placed outside the '''class _HomePageState extends State <HomePage> {}'''

Comment: This is the debug info with the 'assert' : The following assertion was thrown building Item1(dirty):
'package:goodgoals_android/pages/home_page.dart': Failed assertion: line 508 pos 12: 'homepage != null': is not true.

Comment: That didn't answer my questions.  Show the code where you construct an `Item1` object.  Do you intend for `homepage` to be allowed to be `null` or not?

Comment: No, Homepage can never return null

Comment: I have also tried to do "class Item1 extends _HomePageState" but it return a stack overflow error

Comment: You still haven't shown the code that invokes the `Item1` constructor.  Your `Item1` class specifies an optional `homepage` parameter; if that's not supplied, it will be `null`, but you've stated that you don't want it to ever be `null`.  Therefore it should *not* be optional.